# What are some better ways to say "just for confirming"

Tags: email

I want to confirm with my supervisor in an email regarding something that was mentioned at a meeting. What should I use instead of "just for confirming, ..."?

---

Edit: I want to send an email starting with "just for confirming, do we need to examine the generated code, and ..." But instead of "just confirming," which I think is too informal, what other phrases can I use? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This site is not a writers workshop, and even if it were, there is far too little context as presented to offer any sort of useful answer. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: You may write "This is to confirm ...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would remove the word "just" as it doesn't really add anything. Better starts would be:

- To be sure
- To be clear